# Running python script on crontab is causing permissions errors but running via terminal is fine

Tags: python, linux, macos, permissions, cron

I hear that the permissions level via crontab and terminal is totally different.

More specifically, my python script has a command to write a file into the /tmp/ directory. On a linux machine, everything works, both cron and regular shell.

However on OSX, the terminal runs fine but when this command is set on the crontab, an error appears saying that we don't have permissions to write to  the /tmp directory.

How should I handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Afaik, and please correct me if I am wrong, the "permission level" doesn't depend on whether you run something from the shell or if cron runs it, but it depends solely on the user you run it with.

Answer (score -1):

@Lucas Ou-Yang @Hyperboreus
as Hyperboreus said it depends on the user privilege who run it . i think that if you give the /tmp/ dir a 777 permission from the root account it'll be fixed :

### `chmod 777 -R /tmp/`

okay try with : `chmod 777 /tmp/` if the error still check if the directory /tmp/ exist !

Comment: the -R flag in ur command causes an error "-r no such file or directory', but lemme test now, thanks

Comment: -1 Randomly running `chmod 777` in the hope that it will work around a problem is amateurish, poor advice.